# document.getElementsByClassName(variables);

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to target an element through the use of two variables. I know how to do this for id's, but what I'm doing for classes doesn't seem to works. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script>
    var colour = purple;
    var number = 1;
    function check() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName(colour number);
        x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="test" type="text" onblur="check()">
    <div class="1 purple">one</div>
    <div class="2 red">two</div>
    <div class="3 blue">three</div>
    <div class="4 brown">four</div>
    <div class="5 orange">five</div>
    <div class="6 yellow">six</div>
    <div class="7 white">seven</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I've tried both options but neither seems to work. This is the updated script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script>
    function check() {
        var colour = purple;
        var number = one;
        //var x = document.getElementsByClassName(colour + ' ' + number);
        var x = document.querySelector('.' + colour + '.' + number);
        x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test" type="text" onblur="check()">
    <div class="one purple">one</div>
    <div class="two red">two</div>
    <div class="three blue">three</div>
    <div class="four brown">four</div>
    <div class="five orange">five</div>
    <div class="six yellow">six</div>
    <div class="seven white">seven</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note, this is only a test script. Once I get it working, I'll add a lot more divs, one for each color/number combination, so selecting on one class will not work.

Comment: Do you see that notation [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)?

Comment: Use your console... There will be error message there.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm a bit new to coding and I've still a lot to learn. :/

Comment: You do not know what the developer console is yet? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console There is one in chrome, IE, Opera, Safari.

Comment: Thanks, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: purple is not defined" so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the order in which I've put everything?

Comment: No, you are trying to use variables purple and one, not strings...

Comment: Damm, missed that. Thanks that fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `colour number` is not a valid expression.

To specify the class names you need a string with space separated class names, for example `"purple 1"`. Concatenate the strings with a space between them:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(colour + ' ' + number);
```

However, as both the colors and numbers are unique, you only need to look for one of them:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(colour);
```

or:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(number);
```

Note: Class names that are only digits may be problematic in some situations. It's recommended that a class name doesn't start with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You should construct a string:

```
var colour = 'purple';
var number = 1;
var x = document.querySelector('.'+colour+'.'+number);
```

Comment: The `getElementsByClassName` method takes class names separated by spaces, not a CSS selector.

Comment: It does indeed. I should have used document.querySelector